# Topological sort for adjacency Matrix

Tags: time-complexity, adjacency-matrix, topological-sort

Given a graph represented as an adjacency matrix, how can I do a topological sort in linear time?
Even if I do a preprocessor to create an array of the in-degree value it will be with the time complexity of O(|V|^2).
I know that for a topological sort from a matrix it is possible to create an algorithm of linear time, so what am I missing?

Comment: `O(|V|^2)` is linear time. The time is computed with respect to input size, which is `|V|^2` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As dyukha mentioned in the comments, "linear time" is a term that is dependent on the input size. Thus for example the [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) method for testing if a number is prime runs for at most n^(0.5) iterations, but the input size is log(n), so time complexity would be 2^(n/2).

In this case, adjacency matrix takes O(k)=O(|V|^2) space, you can apply [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm) and get linear time, considering finding all vertices with no incoming edges by iterating the matrix takes O(k) time and going over all the edges of a given vertex takes O(k^0.5).

If your intention was whether there exists an algorithm of finding a topological sort in O(|V|), I think any algorithm would at least have to go over all edges, so that might be a lower bound.